# Will this impact my apps speed?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, optimization, intellij-idea

I have read the android developer guide to working on different screen sizes. My question is, **if I only provide an image in the drawable file, and let android scale it for me, will it impact the overall performance of my app?** For example, I am simply displaying a red square, and there aren't any details to the square. Should I provide alternative resources, will android's scaling impact my performance as an app on bigger/smaller screens?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 1):

If you just have a red square, and you want it to scale, I'd use a xml shape drawable instead of an image.  It will perform better as it won't need to scale a bitmap.

Comment: How? They are image buttons, can I still do that?